# bad window token on progressDialog in async task

Tags: android, android-progressbar, android-context

So i am trying to launch a progress dialog from an async task.

in my main activity i am invoking the async task like so:

```
new OCRScanAsyncTask(getApplication().getApplicationContext()).execute();
```

also tried:

```
new OCRScanAsyncTask(getBaseContext()).execute();
```

my asyncTask looks like this:

```
public class OCRScanAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Boolean> {

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.os.AsyncTask#doInBackground(Params[])
     */
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    private String TAG ="OCRAsyncTask";
    private String IMAGE_PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/bcCardReader/tmp/tmpCrd.jpg";
    public static final String DATA_PATH = Environment
            .getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() +"/bcCardReader/tmp/";

    private String lang = "eng";
    private Context context;


    public OCRScanAsyncTask(Context c){
       Log.v(TAG, "*****************CONSTRUCTING");
        context = c;
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute(){

        super.onPreExecute();
        Log.v(TAG, "pre exe");
        progressDialog.setTitle("Please Wait");
        progressDialog.setMessage("Performing Character Recognition");
        progressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.show();

    }
............
```

my error looks like this:
[image]

Comment: Use 'this' instead of getBaseContext() or getApplicationContext()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> bad window token on progressDialog in async task

Most likely is problem with `Context` variable. So my first suggestion is replace your line

```
new OCRScanAsyncTask(getApplication().getApplicationContext()).execute();
```

with

```
new OCRScanAsyncTask(YourActivityName.this).execute();
```

**Note:** I recommend to you to show `progressDialog` before you will start `AsyncTask`.

```
ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog(this); // or YourActivityName.this
pd.setMessage("some message");
pd.show();
AsyncWorker w = new AsyncWorker();
w.execute();
```

Comment: what about if i am calling the method from fragment , will getactivity is cool  ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like context passed through constructor seems to be ApplicationContext ...

Comment: Check the context, it should be an getBaseContext() from an activity